# Is it possible to setup cors rules for partially random urls using wildcard in Asp Net Core Api?

Tags: c#, .net-core, cors

I have an Asp Net Core (3.1) Api where I have specified cors policies like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(name: "MyPolicy",
            builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("https://myurl.com",
                                   )
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials())
            });
    });
}
```

However, I would like to be able to allow any origin that contains "myurl" even though it has a different start or end, as long as it contains "myurl".

E.g., https://adifferentstartthenmyurl.com should be allowed
e.g., https://myurladifferentend.com should also preferably be allowed.

Is this supported in net core 3.1 cors rules? Is it possible to specify a cors policy like this?

I would like to be able to use something like:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(name: "MyPolicy",
            builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("https://*myurl*.com",
                                   )
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials())
            });
    });
}
```

using * as wildcard specifier.

Answer (score -1):

CORS only relaxing strict Same-Origin Policy

Is not possible because it will disable CORS.
With a wildcard in url the CORS will be disabled, because anyone can register additional domain for cross origin attack.

[about CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Requests_with_credentials)

Comment: I know wildcards would affect the cors-rules, and make it easier for potential attackers, but my question is about whether it is possible or not, and if it is supported in asp net core. Not about if it is a good idea to use it or not.

Comment: @ompao is not possible because it will disable CORS